# How to confirm what properties are being bound to in XAML?

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

I've got a "MainModelView" which implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and has a property that exposes an `ObservableCollection<T>` called `ExposedCollection`. In our MainPage.xaml, we have a ListBox whose ItemsSource is supposed to be bound to `MainModelView.ExposedCollection`.

The MainModelView makes a REST call to populate the `ExposedCollection` in the background. When `WebClient` is done doing its thing, the ASyncCallback calls `NotifyPropertyCHanged` which checks if the PropertyChanged event is null, and if not raises it. Pretty basic stuff

Problem is, ListBox never seems to bind to ExposedCollection. I set a breakpoint on our null check for NotifyPropertyChanged, and there are never any listeners on PropertyChanged.

I've tried instantiating MainViewModel in `PhoneApplicationPage.Resources`, in `PhoneApplicationPage.DataContext` and the `PhoneApplicationFrame.DataContext` in App.xaml. In all cases the PropertyChanged event is still null. What am I missing here?

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.DataContext>
    <gmvm:MainViewModel x:Name="MainViewModel" />
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.DataContext>
...
<ListBox x:Name="MyListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding ExposedCollection}" Margin="0,20,-12,0">
.....
</Listbox>
```

Comment: Binding errors are shown in the Output window in Visual Studio. Do you see any binding errors when you run your app?

Comment: There were no errors, but your comment led me on an epic step debug journey that led to a dark corner of the code where the original ref to the collection was left to die by gruesome garbage collection. If you post an answer I'll mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check the Output window in Visual Studio to see if there are any binding errors when running your app.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it makes a difference, but have you tried implementing `ExposedCollection` as a Dependency Property?  If you do that, it might eliminate the need for implementing the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and help with the binding to the listbox?
Crazier things have worked for me...

Comment: Haven't explored Dependency Properties yet, I'll give this a shot after our milestone though. Thanks for the suggestion!